# object Object being written

Tags: javascript, object-construction

I am very new to JS and am playing around trying to output this verify function I came across below.

In my limited thinking I thought that the result would be false and I would be able to write that using document.write(), however it just writes [object Object] refer to https://jsfiddle.net/zyac0etj/

Hoping someone can explain/answer this for me..

```
function MyData(foo, bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;

    this.verify = function () {
        return this.foo === this.bar;
    };
}

\\my addendum
var test = new MyData("myfoo","mybar");
document.write(test);
```

Comment: If you want to print the object you should `JSON.stringify()` it to a string

Comment: try to override toString

Answer (score 0):

This is going on:

```js
console.log(({}).toString());
```

`document.write(str)` expects a `string`. If you pass anything to it which is not a string, that anything's `toString()` method is implicitly invoked. Objects have a `toString()` method which does this:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function() { return '[object Object]'; };
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're just writing the entire object to the DOM, which is why it shows as [object Object]. Assuming you want to get the result of the `verify` function written to the document, you would have to run the verify function in your last line.

The fixed code would look something like this:

```js
function MyData(foo, bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;

    this.verify = function () {
        return this.foo === this.bar;
    };
}

var test = new MyData("myfoo","mybar");

// To see the difference between test and test.verify()
console.log("Test object:", test);
console.log("Verify result:", test.verify());

document.write(test.verify());
```

You can also see the difference between the `test` and `test.verify()` in the console.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I see the error in my thinking now. It should've been document.write(test.verify());

Answer (score 0):

The document.write() method writes a string of text to a document stream.
for more information on [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)